# Uninstall a previous Installed msi created through cx_freeze bdist_msi

Tags: python, windows, windows-installer, distutils, cx-freeze

I often use [cx_freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/) to package my python source with all the dependencies and subsequently create a msi installation package through the [distutils](http://docs.python.org/2/library/distutils.html) [bdist_msi](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/stdlib/distutils.command.bdist_msi.bdist_msi-class.html) extension

The only issues happens when I try to reinstall a newly created msi windows installer without uninstalling the previous version. The uninstaller keeps record of all the previously uninstalled version of the software and that blots registry and uninstaller information.

Is it possible to detect a previously installed version of my software and uninstall it automatically without installing a new version?

I am aware of [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page), and how with its python bindings to create installers, the above issue I mentioned could easily be resolved through it. Unfortunately, at this moment, I am not looking anything beyond what Python provides i.e. distutils.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In cx_Freeze, `bdist_msi` has an option `upgrade-code`, which [the docs](http://cx_freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/distutils.html#bdist-msi) describe as:

> define the upgrade code for the package that is created; this is used
>   to force removal of any packages created with the same upgrade code
>   prior to the installation of this one

To specify it, I think you'd have to pass it to the `setup()` call something like this:

```
options = {"bdist_msi": {"upgrade-code":"..."}}
```

(I always forget whether it should be `-` or `_` in the option names to use them like this, so if that's wrong, try it as `upgrade_code`)

[Microsoft say](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pusu/archive/2009/06/10/understanding-msi.aspx) that the upgrade code should be a GUID (a randomly generated code).

Comment: **+1** Great Answer. Side note about fixing a Windows uninstall gone wrong: Open path `C:\Windows\assembly` and press `Public Key Token` *Column Header* to sort in order. Then look for ***your MSI Public Token*** number (*that of the MSI installation that was **not** removed*) and delete those token entries. Doing this after a bad uninstall will allow for correct re-installation/upgrade, less blotted registry and uninstaller information. Cheers! *P.S. This is how to fix ATi Catalyst Driver and CCC Panel updates gone wrong.*

Comment: Great Answer Indeed. Strangely, I too tried with the upgrade-code before but clueless as to how to use it. Now with your reference to the MS Website stating it should be a random GUID makes sense. I will this the first thing in morning and update on how it fairs.

Comment: I read the link and did this but i can not make installation that remove old one and install new one.this is my `setup.py` http://codepaste.net/fkzojh , can u explain more, how can i change product or package id for installing on old package not a new one ?

Comment: @alireza.m : the `...` was only a placeholder. You should generate a random GUID to put in there. Even then, it will only replace the previous version if that has the same GUID, so you can't use it to remove a version that's already out there before you thought of this.

Comment: @ThomasK thanks for answer, but is there any way to create MSI package that replace old version with new version if there is a old version ?

Comment: @alireza.m : There's no neat way that I know of if you didn't plan it before releasing the old version. It may be possible to write and embed some instructions to remove the old version, but that's probably more hassle than it's worth.

Answer (score 5):

Thomas K's answer is close, but at least in my case, not exact. After some trial and error, I found that the GUID needs to be enclosed in curly brackets:

```
bdist_msi_options = {
    "upgrade_code": "{96a85bac-52af-4019-9e94-3afcc9e1ad0c}"
    }
```

and these options need to be passed in alongside the "build_exe" options (some online examples use other names for these arguments, but I found that only bdist_msi works):

```
setup(  # name, version, description, etc...
        options={"build_exe": build_exe_options, # defined elsewhere
                 "bdist_msi": bdist_msi_options},
        executables=[Executable("run.py",
                                base="win32GUI",
                                shortcutName="My Program name",
                                shortcutDir='ProgramMenuFolder')])
```

With this code, in my case, previous installers were correctly uninstalled and removed from the add/remove programs list.